# How to execute gdb breakpoint commands in batch mode?

Tags: debugging, scripting, automation, gdb, non-interactive

I'm trying to use `gdb` non-interactively - i.e. printing something on every specified breakpoint.

```
$ cat script.gdb
set pagination off
catch syscall
commands
bt
c
end
# It's a hack to get backtraces only on call not on return - Linux and x86_64 specific.
# For sake of this question it can be removed, it will just output more.
condition $bpnum $rax == -38
```

The problem - non-interactive try with batch mode:

```
$ gdb /bin/true -batch -x script.gdb
Catchpoint 1 (any syscall)
Catchpoint 2 (syscall 'fork' [57])

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall brk), 0x00007ffff7df2f9c in brk () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

However if I would run it interactively:

```
$ gdb /bin/true -x script.gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1

...

Reading symbols from /bin/true...
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Catchpoint 1 (any syscall)
Catchpoint 2 (syscall 'fork' [57])
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/true

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall brk), 0x00007ffff7df2f9c in brk () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#0  0x00007ffff7df2f9c in brk () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7df2488 in _dl_sysdep_start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7ddcbc1 in _dl_start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7ddc178 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fffffffe2a5 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

...

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall exit_group), 0x00007ffff7ad7529 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007ffff7ad7529 in _exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a50a2b in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7a50ab5 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000040132d in ?? ()
#4  0x00007ffff7a39c05 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000000401406 in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 35434) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
```

Then it works as intended - breakpoint commands are executed.

Adding additional `-ex c` to the non-interactive command will just add another line of `Catchpoint 1 ...`, but still no backtrace.

Man page and [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) is not helpful.

I guess that there has to be some command that would just wait until it's over or maybe a setting somewhere like the `pagination` one.

I know that I could use something akin to an `expect` script, but I would like to avoid it. Something like this works:

```
echo 'run
quit' | gdb /bin/true -x script.gdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `run` to the end of your script produces the result you want (at least it does when using `GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 8.1-15.fc28`).

> Something like this works:
>
> echo 'run
> quit' | gdb /bin/true -x script.gdb

It works or you *want* it to work?

The `quit` part is redundant -- GDB *will* quit once it reaches the end of script. And the `echo run` part doesn't work because in batch mode GDB will not read its standard input.

Comment: I have to check it, but it had to be a bug in older version. I worked on the Red Hat system with a 3.10 kernel at the time. I'll be able to verify tomorrow the version.

Comment: On gdb 8.0.1 it does not work (the newest from a distro I'm using). But indeed the quit is redundant.
You mean by "the result I want" that if it's used on an unstripped binary it will show backtraces?

Comment: The quit part is redundant, because after `run` is EOF. The `echo run | gdb /bin/true -x script.gdb` command does not use batch mode (no `-batch` flag). That's my workaround for gdb batch mode not working properly at least on this old Red Hat system and on gdb 8.0.1.

I have to check with newer gdb 8.1, but that will take me a while.

Comment: On this Red Hat system I had gdb 8.1. So it does not work as intended on gdb 8.1.